# Is this possible to fit a MMRM (SAS REPEATED) with compound symmetry or AR1 model with glmmTMB?

Tags: mixed-model, repeated-measures, covariance, generalized-estimating-equations, glmmtmb

MMRM (Mixed effect Model Repeat Measurement) models are special cases of the mixed models, where no random effects are used, only the residual covariance is modelled. This is commonly used for analysing repeated measurements. I know, that I can fit this via GLS. GLS is perfect and handles various residual covariances structures, but GLS cannot handle other distributions of the response, for example: logistic model, Poisson, gamma and beta, which I need a lot.

I saw, that the glmmTMB package handles GLM and can employ certain structures in the covariance matrix. But WHICH covariance it pertains? Is this the G (random effects) or R (residual)? In other words, can I get true (!) compound symmetry with glmmTMB, or AR(1), not specifying any random effect, OR by specifying it the way to get appropriate total covariance (which a sum of G and R)? I say "true", because I just learned that the random intercept model is different than the compound symmetry. In certain cases it may match or may not.

A note about MMRM models:
https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-sig-mixed-models/2018q1/026583.html
and
https://www.psiweb.org/docs/default-source/resources/psi-subgroups/scientific/2015/estimands-28-09-2015/jamesroger.pdf?sfvrsn=bba3d0db_2

Is the GEE the only alternative to GLS in this case?

Comment: @BenBolker , Is this possible?

Comment: What does MMRM stand for ?

Comment: Mixed effect Model Repeat Measurement. It's one of standards in certain industries for analysing longitudinal data. As I wrote in my post, it's like "random-effect model" without random effects, only the residual covariance is used. It's usually modelled using GLS estimation or GEE, but the first doesn't handle GLM family, and the latter requires more data and missing data must follow the "missing completely at random" pattern.